# Iterate through array in Cypress with assertions JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, iteration, cypress

I have an array from API call response that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "IsDatalakeEnabled": true,
        "RecoveryHr": {
            "IsRecoveryHREnabled": false,
            "RecoveryHeartRateInterval": 120,
            "RecoveryHeartRateSessionTime": 300
        }
    }
]
```

I need to get each key:value pair and make assertion that each one exists in other API call response body that looks like this:

```
...
"StudioAddress": null,
        "StudioProfileLanguage": {
            "LanguageName": "English",
            "LanguageCode": "en"
        },
        "IsDiversityChannel": true,
        "TotalDiversityRadios": 2,
        "IsDatalakeEnabled": false,
        "IsNetpulse": false,
        "RecoveryHeartRateInterval": 120,
        "RecoveryHeartRateSessionTime": 300,
        "IsRecoveryHREnabled": false,
        "StudioPhysicalLocationId": null,
        "StudioLocation": null,
        "IsIntroCapacityEnabled": false,
        "Status": null,
        "IsWeb": false,
        "OrangeBook": null,
        "IsFeReservationEnabled": true,
        "TimeZone": "America/New_York",
        "IsModifyMaxHr": false,
        "IsRunRowEnabled": false,
        "WeightMeasure": "LB",
...
```

Tried cy.each(), but it treats it like one object:

```
{
    "TotalDiversityRadios": "0",
    "IsDatalakeEnabled": true
}
```

Any suggestions/hints would be greatly appreciated. thank you!

tried to convert response body object into array using _.castArray()
Also, tried Object.entries()

---

Update 01/14/2023
@adoff This is how my test looks like:

```js
validateStudioSettings() {
        cy.intercept('POST', '**/studio-settings').as('post')
        cy.contains('APPLY').should('be.enabled').click()
        cy.get('.dialog-content').should('be.visible').and('have.text', 'Are you sure you want to apply these settings?')
        cy.contains('AGREE').click()
        cy.get('.notification').should('be.visible').and('contain', 'Success').and('contain', 'Update studio settings successfully.')
        cy.wait('@post').then(post => {
            expect(post.response.statusCode).equal(200)
            expect(post.response.statusMessage).equal('OK')
            expect(post.response.body).equal('Update studio settings successfully.')
            let studios = _.castArray(post.request.body.StudioIds)
            let settings = _.castArray(post.request.body.Settings)//.map(([key, val]) => key + ': ' + val);
            console.log('Studios: ', studios)
            console.log('Settings: ', settings)
            cy.wrap(studios).each((studioId, index) => {
                console.log('StudioId: ', studioId, index)
                let idToken = localStorage.getItem("idToken")
                cy.request({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: `/` + studioId,
                    headers: {
                        'authorization-cognito': idToken
                    }
                }).then(response => {
                    cy.wrap(settings).each((setting) => {
                        console.log('Setting: ', setting)
                        cy.wrap(response).its('body').then(body => {
                            let el = _.castArray(body)
                            console.log('Body: ', el)
                            expect(el).to.contain(setting)
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    }
```

With this code I'm getting error in Cypress runner:
[Cypress Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YljLc.png)
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8srwT.png)

Comment: How are you getting these arrays? What Cypress code are you running? Without seeing how you're trying to do this in Cypress, it will be difficult to offer a Cypress solution

Comment: @agoff I updated post with test code, thanks

Answer (score 4):

This could be done by checking key/value using `Object.entries(obj)` to give an array of key/value which would be compared to the expected object's key/value.

But there is nesting in the response.

Perhaps you could flatten the response first?

Here's a sample function that would help

```js
const object = {
  IsDatalakeEnabled: true,
  RecoveryHr: {
    IsRecoveryHREnabled: false,
    RecoveryHeartRateInterval: 120,
    RecoveryHeartRateSessionTime: 300,
  },
};

function keyValues(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      const kvs = keyValues(value);
      acc = acc.concat(kvs);
    } else {
      acc.push([key, value]);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(keyValues(object))
/*
(4) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
 0: (2) ['IsDatalakeEnabled', true]
 1: (2) ['IsRecoveryHREnabled', false]
 2: (2) ['RecoveryHeartRateInterval', 120]
 3: (2) ['RecoveryHeartRateSessionTime', 300]
 length: 4
*/
```

In the test:

```js
const expected = {
  ...
  "IsDatalakeEnabled": false,
  "IsNetpulse": false,
  "RecoveryHeartRateInterval": 120,
  "RecoveryHeartRateSessionTime": 300,
  ...
}

function keyValues(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      const kvs = keyValues(value);
      acc = acc.concat(kvs);
    } else {
      acc.push([key, value]);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

cy.request(...)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    const obj = data[0]
    const kvs = keyValues(obj)
    kvs.forEach([key, value] => {
      expect(expected(key)).to.eq(value)
    })
  })
```

Comment: thanks, I will try that. Should I pass 'setting' value to function as 'obj'?